# Not all data in being outputted Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

Trying to scrape following website, https://www.trollandtoad.com/magic-the-gathering/aether-revolt/10066, and it scrapes almost all the data perfectly but in certain situations where there are many sellers for a particular card and their is a button that says view more it will not get all the prices for the different sellers, even though all the needed data is in the html code whether I click view more or not.  For example in the pictures below you will see the card before and after the view more button is clicked and it will scrape 7 of the 8 cards the only one is does not scrape is the Evo Merchant card for 7.99, the one that appears right after I click view more, but the two below it, paradise games for 2.98 and Evo merchant for 6.99, get **scraped** just fine so I do not know what is going on.

```
def parse(self, response):
        for game in response.css('div.card > div.row'):
            item = GameItem()
            item["Card_Name"]  = game.css("a.card-text::text").get()
            for buying_option in game.css('div.buying-options-table div.row:not(:first-child)'):
                item["Condition"] = buying_option.css("div.col-3.text-center.p-1::text").get()
                item["Price"] = buying_option.css("div.col-2.text-center.p-1::text").get()
                yield item
```

[image: Screenshot of website]
[image: Screenshot of website]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem lies in your CSS selector, specifically, the `:not(:first-child)` part.

I haven't looked into the HTML carefully, but apparently the first item after the "View More" link is also considered a first child. So I would consider removing that table header some other way:

```
for buying_option in game.css('div.buying-options-table div.row')[1:]:
```

Comment: You're welcome! I was about to test this because I haven't used scrappy before, and I was not sure whether `css` returns a sliceable list or a generator. A little tip: When putting a code example in your question, try to test it in isolation to make sure it doesn't depend on anything else you have in your code (if at all possible). In your case, that might mean changing `GameItem()` to `{}`. Of course those are small issues answerers can handle themselves, but the less you frustrate the answerers, the more likely you will get an answer!